# vim find replace pattern matching backslash and strings

Tags: linux, vim

Using vim find and replace, how can one find and replace string pattern such as this:
`/local/this/drive/opt/script/` with `/remote/script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in Vim you can use not only the slash character as separator:

```
:%s_/this/drive/opt/script/_/remote/script_g
```